# Inability to understand local fourier analysis in the given link

Tags: image-processing

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235662494_On_separating_overlapped_fingerprints
[Paper name-"On separating  overlapped fingerprint", author-Fanglin Chen,Jianjiang Feng,Jie Zhou]
I am unable to understand the process of local fourier analysis in the initial orientation field estimation. I have tried searching over the internet but in vain. [image]

The sentence I am unable to understand has been marked in the paper. What is this 16 x 16 and then again from where do i get this 64 x 64? I can apply a gaussian filter by taking each pixel as centre. But how can i do that taking a 16 x 16 block as centre? The meaning of that sentence is absolutely unclear to me.
I have looked at the original paper from where this has been taken and also this paper (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261469993_Automatic_segmentation_of_latent_fingerprints)
[Paper-Automatic Segmentation of Latent Fingerprint author-Anil K.Jain]
but things are very unclear to me.
Please, I would request the community to kindly help me. I am stuck at this for the last 2 weeks.
Thanks in advance to anyone who will help me

Comment: Please provide a full reference, including title and authors of the paper, so that others with a similar question can find this via search.  We have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1201/). Thank you!

Comment: Please transcribe text and mathematics, so the question can be found via search and so that this is accessible to individuals with visual impairments.  Note that your "this paper" is not going to work for anyone else.  Please proof-read your post.

Comment: (Can you please include `/D:`?)

Comment: (To me, *16×16 pixels* looks arbitrary. I take an *64×64 [pixel] window* to be centred "at each block" - which includes 9 blocks completely, one half of 12 blocks and one quarter of 4 more.) The title of the first paper lacks the trailing/plural `s`. The importance of such detail can be seen in the second reference: I don't have access to your "device D:", and title and author as stated give diverse search engine near misses.

Comment: Many many thanks for replying @greybeard sir. But , I would like to know, how you can centre on a block and multiply the local image in 64 x 64 window with gaussian function...I am unable to visualize it. Gaussian filtering would require centering on a pixel for a block of certain size and that block size needs to be odd, I do not know how to filter by centering on a block. If you can kindly provide further explanation or point out relevant resources, it would be of great help.

Comment: I think that you are interpreting in combination what was unfortunately worded in the paper in the first place. I read: a) a 64×64 window gets centred b) the data in the window gets filtered (with the "innermost pixels" at a distance of $2^{-½}$?! Wouldn't it be fun to give [Manhattan distance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) a try here.).

Comment: @greybeard Sir, which innermost pixels are you talking about?Is it the innermost pixels of 64 x 64 or innermost pixels of 16 x 16?

Comment: Both: `Is it the innermost pixels of 64 x 64` yes `innermost pixels of 16 x 16` yes, again: the way I read *window centered at each block*, the window exceeds the block with the same centre by 24 pixels in every direction.

Comment: @greybeard Sir, I got this point of yours. But then I will have to leave out blocks whose sides coincide with the image boundary. In that case, should I use padding?? Also another question, the DFT operation mentioned there, after performing it on 64 x 64, should I try to concatenate the 64 x 64 DFT images???